# omxplayer doesn't play audio

Tags: audio

I can play audio to analog jack output with mplayer and aplay, but i cannot get it working with omxplayer.

```
# setup audio output
modprobe snd_bcm2835
amixer cset numid=3 1

# This is working
mplayer -vo fbdev big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi

# This is not working (video ok, no audio)
omxplayer big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi

# Even this is not working
omxplayer -o local big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi
```

omxplayer's output:

```
Video codec omx-mpeg4 width 1280 height 720 profile 0 fps 24.000000
Audio codec ac3 channels 6 samplerate 48000 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
```

Video is playing, but without audio. Pulse isn't installed.

Comment: With a fresh raspbian it works. It seems something related to kernel, because I've recompiled the kernel, same version and same configuration with some modules added.

Comment: I have the opposite problem, *only* omxplayer works, aplay doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I found a solution.
You have to put your *GPU memory* at a reasonable level.

In the file **/boot/config.txt**,
add the line **gpu_mem=128**

> From Steven Hickson:
>   "Also make sure your gpu_mem split is at a reasonable level such as
>   128/128 by adding the line **gpu_mem=128** in the **/boot/config.txt** file in
>   the newer firmware versions."

Source: http://stevenhickson.blogspot.se/2012/08/setting-up-omxplayer-gui-on-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score 2):

You may need to force HDMI output with the following command:

```
omxplayer -o hdmi x.avi
```

Worked with Raspberry Pi 3, Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch), Bluetooth audio device.

Comment: Gollum, do you mean to use `alsa` or `hdmi` as the audio output device?